# How to check if the user is created in the database and delete it

Tags: python, mysql, sql, selenium

I have currently written my signup test using python page object method. I want to add logging in to the database and checking the user i created and then deleted it. I would like to add that in my teardown method. How can I achieve it using sql to make a more robust test

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import unittest
import sys


class BaseTestCase(object):


    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.driver.get("https://marketplace.appdirect.com/login")
        self.assertEqual("Log In | AppDirect", self.driver.title)



    def tearDown(self):
        if sys.exc_info()[0]:
            test_method_name = self._testMethodName
            # if the test fails, the code below will take a screenshot
            self.driver.save_screenshot("/Users/Desktop/AppDirect/Screenshots" + test_method_name + ".png") 
        self.driver.quit()


from selenium                                 import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui            import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.select        import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support               import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by             import By
from abc                                      import abstractmethod




class LocatorMode:

 XPATH = "xpath"
 CSS_SELECTOR = "cssSelector"
 NAME = "name"
 ID = "id"
 TAG_NAME = "tagName"


class BasePage(object):

 def __init__(self, driver):
     self.driver = driver


 @abstractmethod
 def _verify_page(self):
     """
     This method verifies that we are on the correct page.
     """
     return 

 def wait_for_element_visibility(self, waitTime, locatorMode, Locator):
     element = None
     if   locatorMode == LocatorMode.ID:
          element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, waitTime).\
                  until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, Locator)))
     elif locatorMode == LocatorMode.NAME:
          element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, waitTime).\
                  until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, Locator)))
     elif locatorMode == LocatorMode.XPATH:
          element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, waitTime).\
                  until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, Locator)))
     elif locatorMode == LocatorMode.CSS_SELECTOR:
          element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, waitTime).\
                  until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, Locator)))
     else:
         raise Exception("Unsupported locator strategy.")
     return element


 def wait_until_element_clickable(self, waitTime, locatorMode, Locator):
     element = None
     if   locatorMode == LocatorMode.ID:
          element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, waitTime).\
                  until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, Locator)))
     elif locatorMode == LocatorMode.NAME:
          element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, waitTime).\
                  until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, Locator)))
     elif locatorMode == LocatorMode.XPATH:
          element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, waitTime).\
                  until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, Locator)))
     elif locatorMode == LocatorMode.CSS_SELECTOR:
          element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, waitTime).\
                  until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, Locator)))
     else:
         raise Exception("Unsupported locator strategy.")
     return element



 def find_element(self, locatorMode, Locator):
     element = None
     if locatorMode == LocatorMode.ID:
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_id(Locator)
     elif locatorMode == LocatorMode.NAME:
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_name(Locator)
     elif locatorMode == LocatorMode.XPATH:
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(Locator)
     elif locatorMode == LocatorMode.CSS_SELECTOR: 
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(Locator)
     else:
        raise Exception("Unsupported locator strategy.")
     return element


 def fill_out_field(self, locatorMode, Locator, text):
     self.find_element(locatorMode, Locator).clear()
     self.find_element(locatorMode, Locator).send_keys(text)

 def click(self, waitTime, locatorMode, Locator):
     self.wait_until_element_clickable(waitTime, locatorMode, Locator).click()



class IncorrectPageException(Exception):
 """
 This exception is raised when we try to instantiate the wrong page.
 """


from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import unittest
import sys


class SignupPage(BasePage):

     def clickSignupButton(self. driver):
        self.click(10, "xpath", "//a[contains(.,'Sign Up')]")
        self.assertEqual("Sign Up for AppDirect", self.driver.title)

    def setEmail(self, email):
        self.fill_out_field("id", "id_email", email)
        self.click(10, "xpath", "//button[@name='userSignupButton']")

    def setName(self, first, last):
        self.fill_out_field("id", "id_first_name", first)
        self.fill_out_field("id", "id_last_name", last)

    def setPassword(self, password):
        self.fill_out_field("id", "id_password", password)
        self.fill_out_field("id", "id_password_confirmation", password)

    def setProductName(self, name):
        self.fill_out_field("id", "id_first_product_name", name)

      def submit(self):
        self.click(10, "cssSelector", "#create_account_form button")

from selenium import webdriver
import unittest
from BaseTestCase import BaseTestCase
from BasePage import BasePage
from SignupPage import SignupPage




class SignupTest(BaseTestCase, unittest.TestCase):


    def setUp(self):
        super(SignupTest, self).setUp()


    # Positive Test Case
    def test_SignupTest(self):
        # enter the username, password, email etc



    def tearDown(self):
        super(SignupTest, self).tearDown()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I know that adding it in the teardown method will be a great code. Any thoughts???

Comment: Unless I misunderstand the purpose of the test, you don't want this in your teardown method. It's a validation that's part of the test. What if the user isn't created in the db? Wouldn't that be an indication that the test failed?

Comment: Having said that, the code you posted doesn't really have anything to do with the actual question. Please create an [mcve] of the SQL method you are using to query the db, return the existence of the user, etc. so we can help you figure out why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL would be along the lines:

```
Delete From <table_name> Where <Unique_Column> = <Value>
```

Where:

- table_name is the table that fosters your users.
- Unique_Column is the field you want to check, e.g.. `UserId`
- Value = The unique value for the filter, e.g. `37`

For example:

```
Select * from users where userId = 37
```

If you run this query from code, the callback will show how many rows were affected by this operation, which means 0 = no users found, otherwise you found results.

Comment: how i would integrate that in the teardown method